# Современные реалии или перспективный вид бизнеса

Tags: работа

Приветствую!

Как вы считаете: какие на данный момент области ведения бизнеса наиболее перспективны, востребованы? Какие сферы, отрасли? Не только в нашей стране, но и вцелом - в мире. Либо могут возникнуть какие-то новые сферы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа для программиста появляется тогда, когда возникает что-то новое в IT: новое железо, новая операционная систем и т.п. Сейчас вперед выходят продукты Google: Android и Chrome OS. Android, видимо, распространится на все мобильные и бытовые устройства от телефонов до телевизоров. А Chrome OS - на все ноутбуки. Соответственно возникнет необходимость по разработке приложений для всех этих платформ.

С другой стороны, время разработки приложений на продажу как таковых (блокнот, сапер, офисный редактор, графический редактор) уходит в прошлое: уже почти все необходимое сделано, осталось лишь улучшать и поддерживать. И фокус смещается на разработку и производство программных средств, которые не являются вещью в себе, а обеспечивают доступ к какой-либо услуге. На примере социальных сетей: продажа движка для социальной сети не приносит сейчас такого дохода, который приносит успешная социальная сеть, если она удачна.

Comment: Из ваших слов можно обобщить, что сейчас на гребне популярности(или скоро будет на гребне): 
1.Мобильные платформы
2.Стартапы, веб-ориентированные решения, сервисы, соц сети

Но все же я спрашиваю сферы бизнеса: экономика, наука и направления которые востребованы перспективные или будут перспективны. То бишь немного оттолкнуться от программирования, разработки ПО хочется.
Кроме того: инет-магазин возьмем, тут есть программисткая часть(создание магазина), а есть бизнес часть - именно товары, услуги, которые и будут продоваться. Немного сумбурно, но смысл ясен:)

Answer (score 0):

Например, программирование под Android. Думаю, вполне перспективное направление.

Comment: Хахаха:) Да уж....не ощущается пока что этого. Кроме того сферы не только связанные с программированием, хотя компьютреные технологии уже во всех сферах.